# From mySql result to Json using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm having some issue running my php script,
It load data from mysql then encoded to json (it should be simple):
Here is the script :

```
<?php require_once('../includes/dbConnect.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('../includes/dbFunctions.php'); ?>
<?php
    $db = new DB_Functions();
    $output = array();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM Users");
        if ($result) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $output[]=$row;
            }
            print(json_encode($output));
        } else {
                $output_no = array('response'=>'no');
                print(json_encode($output_no));
        }
?>
```

and return is :
Response does not contain any data. in Advanced Rest Application Tool

I have checked out the $output it gives 60 rows, but encoded it to json it does NOT work.
What's wrong with my php code ?

Comment: Maybe the script is getting an error. Check your PHP error log.

Comment: You shouldn't use `mysql_query` anymore.

Comment: var_dump($row) gives wat??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this,

1. Check what is coming (as array) from the Database. For this you can use `var_dump($row);`
2. For pushing the values into the array try this, `array_push($output, $row);`
3. I use something like this which you may find useful in future:

   ```
   $result = new stdClass();
   $result->name = $something;
   $result->value = $bla_bla;

   json_encode($result);
   ```

**EDIT**

For Example the DB gives go the names John, Mary, Smith in $row['name'] where `name` is the field where the names are stored in your table.

I recommend you to make a function to create JSON which saves alot of rewriting the same code.

```
 function MakeJSON($output){
    $result = new stdClass();
    $result->names = $output;
    return json_encode($result);
 }
```

**STOP USING mysql**

Comment: point 1 & 2 has been already tested with no success array is not empty as I said and result is not there, I m right now testing point 3

Comment: how should I implement the point 3 in my code ?